# How to push small local changes to remote server with Git and Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, git, git-ftp

I'm new into Git and I'm working with Wordpress themes. 
I was always using FTP client to push every small change into my remote server... I mean sometimes it was just one line of code to check the change of CSS. It was easy and nice but there will be always problem with reverting changes and since I'm learning Git, I want to change it.

I've found two ways to do it:

- git-ftp
- i've tried to connect my local respository with GitHub and my intention was to automatic pull changes into my remote server from GitHub (it's not working yet, i need to configure it better)

BUT, do I have to commit every single small change? Because I cant just save file and check changes with Browsersync on second monitor, I will have to commit so many times. Also which way will be better for me - maybe there are another, better ways?

I really want to improve my performance, but it looks like that's not easy or I'm doing something wrong? I know about existence things like WP-CLI, webpack, gulp but often I'm creating small websites and probably I will spend more time on configurating those things than create theme. Also I thought about working on localhost, but I really think that I'm complicating things and my job.

Really sorry if it's wrong section, but I'm new on stackoverflow - hey! I will be really thankful if you can help me, because I think that i need knowledge of someone experienced.

Comment: Test changes locally and only commit (and push) when changes are ready for staging/production environment.

Comment: If you don't want to develop your site locally -as it seems it's your intention after re-reading your post- then what you're doing is the way to go.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I thought about testing changes on local server but what with mysql base updates?

Comment: Ah, that's an entirely different issue than the one you originally described above. Some of the answers from this question might help with that: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/272801/syncing-local-content-with-development-staging-sites

Comment: really thank you, I think that i should make a better research. one quesiton - should I develop sites in local server? is it better than developing on remote?

Comment: Personally, I prefer working on a local server because to me it's faster this way: I don't need to keep pushing changes to an external server, I can just check if things work or not on my local server (Xampp, Docker, etc.) This also helps keeping the commits log clean as I don't have to commit every single change, as I mentioned earlier I only commit/push changes that I know are working as intended.

Comment: really thank you. i dont know how i could work only on remote server for few years...  now it's much better :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur to be helpful but I'll try :

First, even for a small project, I always prefer to install a local environment for testing. It avoid risks on your remote server !

You can take a look here : https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/tutorials/installing-a-local-server/

Then, if you have an SSH access to your server, may be you can try to configure it to push directly from your local environment to your remote server. Here is a simple tutorial : https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa

Comment: Hey! Maybe it's a good idea, but what with mysql base updates? I mean the situation (for example) when on local server I will create a few posts in WP... how to connect them to remote server?

Comment: You shouldn't do that because you can make mistake on your local environment and if you use the same database between local and remote, you can break your remote server. A lot of persons prefer to have separated databases for security reasons. But you can make a backup of your production environment for example with "mysqldump -uMyUserSql -p MyDatabaseName > myBackup.sql" and import it on your local env. But never from local to remote, be careful :P

Comment: that's a good idea! :D but what I have to do when I end coding my layout from .psd and my client wants to check website? I think that in this situation I should push actual website from local to remote server, manually update database and... what about small fixes (when client wants to change something) on website? should I abandon my local server and make them on remote server? or... update local WP -> download mysql base -> update base in remote server?

Comment: A common workflow I see every where is : Client Issue => modification local code => test on local machine (import remote database if needed) => validate => commit and note modification that are not about code (new entries in databases, schema update, script to call, environment update etc...) => pass your website in maintenance mode => git pull and apply your other changes => be happy, disable maintenance mode. It is heavy, but secured. I always use this for my web applications, not for wordpress so it can change ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what remote system or vps you are using.
It could be from GCP, AWS, DIGITAL OCEAN, or WP itself.
It looks like that you are using the wordpress hosting your website.
If so, you might use wp cli to login the server.
①As for the frequent testing and updating, it is a good idea to copy the remote project to your localhost. Run your web app using wampserver. And create a new repository in the github and connect it with your local folder.
Then you could use git to version control your codes, do pull and push, stash or whatever.
And after testing, you could upload the specific files or folder to the remote server via ftp or sftp periodically.
②Another way is to install the git bash or git software in your server side.
It depends on the OS you are using. If it is a win or linux.

```
$ add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
$ apt update; apt install git
```

and create new user, add it into the sudo group
create a repository in your server side and link it to the github remote repository.

I am not sure whether the second way would work.
I recommend you try the first method.
Hope this could help. Happy coding.